# Using a parameter passed into xslt stylesheet

Tags: xslt, parameters, saxon, xsl-stylesheet

I am using `Saxon` to perform a transformation of an XML document in my .NET application. I am passing in a parameter to my `xslt` document but I have no idea how to use it in my template.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
var zipcode = _db.AXCustomers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ACCOUNTNUM == accNo).ZIPCODE;
transformer.SetParameter(new QName("CustomerZipCode"), new XdmAtomicValue(zipcode));
```

Then in my `xslt` document I am specifying the parameter like so:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="CustomerZipCode" />
```

But when I try to use the parameter, nothing appears. I am using it like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($CustomerZipCode, ' ')"/>
```

But nothing is output even though my `zipcode` does contain a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `xsl:param` inside a `xsl:template` element, it means that the param is for the template. The parameter you are passing from the .net code is a transformer parameter and related `xsl:param` must be placed at the top level of the stylesheet, into the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, thought it was something simple!